# Used named ranges in VBA

Tags: vba

from1,from2,from3,to1,to2,to3 are all pre-defined named ranges. They all have the same dimension. I'm just trying to replace all the to's with all the from's.

The following code keeps giving me a type mismatch error on this line

```
 ThisWorkbook.Names(to_ranges(i)) = ThisWorkbook.Names(from_ranges(i))
```

Could someone help? Thank you!

```
Sub named_ranges()
    Dim from_ranges() As Variant, to_ranges() As Variant
    from_ranges() = Array("from_1", "from_2", "from_3")
    to_ranges() = Array("to_1", "to_2", "to_3")
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To UBound(from_ranges)
        ThisWorkbook.Names(to_ranges(i)) = ThisWorkbook.Names(from_ranges(i))
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: change `Names` to `Range`

Comment: @Darren Bartrup-Cook Sorry.. I've fixed that.

Comment: Deleted my comment after you did.... sorry,  your comment looks out of place now (you missed the one in the code).. :)

Comment: `ThisWorkbook.Names(from_ranges(i))`  agree with scott should be range.

Comment: How did you manage to assign "to1", "to2", "to3" as names? Those are valid cell addresses and typically, you cannot use a valid cell address as a name.

Comment: Sorry but my understanding is .names is for the whole workbook and .range is for specific worksheet. Here I'm trying avoid referencing each specific worksheet so I pre defined the named ranges. Why wouldn't .names work?

Comment: @Jeeped Sorry. Those are terrible example names. I've changed them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define a named range you define it's scope (worksheet or workbook). So:

```
Range(to_ranges(i)) = Range(from_ranges(i))
```

Will probably work just fine as the default scope for a named range is "Workbook".

That being said, you can use the `.Names` object here as well, you just need to get it's `.RefersToRange` property otherwise you aren't copying a range, instead you are copying the default property of the `Name` object which is its "RefersToRange" which is just a string.

Essentially you are doing:

```
Names(to_ranges(i)).RefersToRange = Names(from_ranges(i)).RefersToRange
```

Which is incorrect.

Instead (and this is total overkill compared to the first example above):

```
Range(Names(to_ranges(i)).RefersToRange).Value = Range(Names(from_ranges(i)).RefersToRange).Value
```

And... ultimately this doesn't solve your initial concern of Name scopes (workbook vs worksheet) as the `RefersToRange` will be scoped as it was was defined and may still end up hitting your `ActiveSheet` if it improperly scoped AND left unqualified here.

Comment: Range(to_ranges(i)) = Range(from_ranges(i)) actually gives me an error. "Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed"

Comment: Double check that those named ranges truly exist in the workbook and that they are scoped to the workbook. It sounds like at least one of those named ranges isn't rectifying.